# Proof that Curl and Divergence Uniquely Define Vector Field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Why/how do curl and divergence yield a unique vector field? Can anyone give me a proof? Also can you construct a vector field from *any* curl/divergence?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this page for the [Helmholtz decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition).

Comment: Muchas Gracias.